# How can the performance of java application be ensured when there is no control when garbage collection occurs?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was doing some reading and found out that when GC occurs with a "stop and copy" strategy or any other the program execution is rightfully stopped to have an effective GC. This brings me to the question, How can the performance of java application be ensured when there is no control when garbage collection occurs as the GC stops the program execution when it occurs?

Say we have several threads running one of which is working on a very performance critical activity, which requires milliseconds of precision, at that moment can I rely on my Java application, what will happen if the GC is called in such critical time, will it not effect the performance, are there ways that I can make sure that the GC is not called at certain time in the code?

Comment: Take a look: [HotSpot VM Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/)

Comment: You can't. But it depends how much pressure you put on the gc - it may be smooth enough for your needs. If not you can use out-of-heap memory and manage it manually or a real time JVM or use a non-gc language like c/c++.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Hi!, I was hoping someone could simplify the details, so that before jumping into the details I have the bigger picture. Would you care to brief be about it?

Comment: Oracle has a article about [Real-Time Java programming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/nilsen-realtime-pt1-2264405.html) that you might want to read.  [Part 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/nilsen-realtime-pt2-2264409.html) has a section about dealing with GC.

Comment: How many milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options

- use a small young generation size.  This can be collected in a few milli-seconds, sometime less than 1 milli-second.
- use a large Eden space and create less garbage.  If you create less than 300 KB/s on average and you have an Eden space of 24 GB, you can run for a whole day without even a minor collection.

While not all libraries are designed to be low GC, you can still use them provided they are not called very often. For critical path libraries you want them to be low garbage.  This not only reduce pause times, but speeds up the code between pauses sometimes as much as 2-5x.